# Remote control for SamsungTV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, remote-control

I have an iOS app that connects to my Samsung TV via local network and simulates the remote control. Now I'm trying to do the same on the PC (NodeJS/C#/Python/...).

Is there a documentation somewhere for doing that? Or does anyone have a piece of code?

How do I connect to the TV? How do I control it over the connection?

Comment: same as from your ios app

Comment: It's just an app - not open sourced...

Comment: [My own implementation](https://github.com/piu130/samsung-tv-remote-interface) in NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this site: https://sites.google.com/site/moosyresearch/projects/samsung_shape

They have doing a research for the WAM speakers. As they say it also should work for SamsungTV's.

There is a command cine tool, which you can send for example `KEY_VOLDOWN` or `KEY_VOLUP` to the tv.

Under the article SOAP, you can find the tool.

Answer (score 1):

look at 
https://github.com/Ape/samsungctl
Use pip3 not pip for install.
Works for me with Samsung K Series :0) on Raspberry Pi from command line.
I trying to integrate it to Openhab2.

Comment: For K Series is it necessary to use method-websocket. On first connection with TV you musst agree with connection on TV screen (pairing).

Answer (score 0):

look at 
https://github.com/Ape/samsungctl
Use pip3 not pip for install.
Works for me with Samsung K Series :0) on Raspberry Pi from command line.
I trying to integrate it to Openhab2.
Domoticz integration:
https://www.domoticz.com/wiki/Plugins/SamsungTV.html
Look at google with:samsungctl